# Choosing in menu wirh arrows on keyboard (C#)

Tags: c#, console-application, arrows

I am trying to make a simple menu where I can choose with the arrows on the keyboard. I can run the code and the program doesn't give any errors, however I can not choose with the arrows and nothing happens if I press Enter, the choice always remains on the first choice (New customer). That will say, It always stays like this:

> Hello and welcome! please choose type of registration:
>
> *New customer <--
>
> New staff
>
> Service
>
> Reparation
>
> Garantie

My code this far is:

```
using System;

namespace uppdrag_2.cs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] menuOptions = new string[] {"New customer\t", "New staff\t", "Serivce\t", "Reparation", "Garantie" };
            int menuSelect = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.CursorVisible = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Hello and welcome! Please choose type of registration:");

                if (menuSelect == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[0] + "<--");
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[2]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[3]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[4]);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else if (menuSelect == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[1] + "<--");
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[2]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[3]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[4]);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else if (menuSelect == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[2] + "<--");
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[3]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[4]);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else if (menuSelect == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[2]);
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[3] + "<--");
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[4]);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else if (menuSelect == 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[2]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[3]);
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[4] + "<--");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                var keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();

                if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow && menuSelect != menuOptions.Length - 1)
                {
                    menuSelect++;
                }
                else if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow && menuSelect >= 1)
                {
                    menuSelect--;
                }
                else if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    switch (menuSelect)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            Newcustomer();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            NewStaff();
                                break;
                        case 2:
                            Service();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Reparation();
                                break;
                        case 4:
                            Garantie();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static void Newcustomer(){
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to registrate a new customer!");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter name of customer:");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter car brand:");
            string carBrand = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter model of car");
            string model = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter year model");
            string yearModel = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter how many km the car has been driven");
            string km = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Registration compleated!");
            Console.WriteLine("You have registered a new customer! You have registrered" + " " + name + " " + "with the carbrand" + carBrand + " " + "of model" + " " + model + " " + "form year" + " " + yearModel + " " + "That has been driven" + " " + km + "km.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void NewStaff(){
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to registrer a new staffmember!");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter name of staffmember:");
            string staffName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter age:");
            string ageStaff = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter work position of the new staffmember:");
            string position = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter type of contract:");
            string contract = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter date of the workers first day:");
            string start = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter date of the workrs last day:");
            string end = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Registration compleated!");
            Console.WriteLine("You have registrered a new staffmember! The following information has been registered:\t" + "name: " + staffName + "\t" + "age: " + ageStaff + "\t" + "position: " + position + "\t" + "Contract: " + contract + "\t" + "First day: " + start + "\t" + "Last day: " + end);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void Service(){
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter type of service:");
            string service = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of an registered customer. If customer is not already registered, please press Enter to return to menu and choose `New customer`");
            string customerservice = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter staffmember responsible for this matter. If staffmember is new, please press Enter to return to the menu and choose ``New staff`");
            string servicestaff = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter staring day of service:");
            string serviceStart = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter deadline of servicematter:");
            string deadline = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Service matter registrered!");
            Console.WriteLine("Following information has been registrered:\t" + "Service matter: " + service + "\t" + "Customer: " + customerservice + "\t" + "Staff member responsible: " + servicestaff + "\t" + "Startdate of service matter: " + serviceStart + "\t" + "Deadline: " + deadline);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void Reparation(){
            Console.WriteLine("You have choosen to registrer a reparation matter!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void Garantie(){
            Console.WriteLine("You have choosen to registrate a garantie matter!");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone who could help me figure out what I`ve done wrong?

Comment: Edit your question and fix the code formatting, then add the tag for the programming language the question is about (Java?), or nobody will find it.

Comment: Okay! I have written now that it is C# i`m writing in, but what do you mean by "fix the code formatting" (sorry I`m very new to programing)

Comment: You have `Console.ReadLine()` after each set of menu options are written - this blocks execution as it's waiting for input. Any reason you have these `Console.ReadLine()` calls there?

Comment: Okay! I removed them and now it works, thank you!

Comment: I dont know why I had written them there haha

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your menu code quite a bit by using a `for` loop and a [ternary if statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] menuOptions = new string[] { "New customer\t", "New staff\t", "Serivce\t", "Reparation\t", "Garantie\t" };
        int menuSelect = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello and welcome! Please choose type of registration:");

            for (int i = 0; i < menuOptions.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((i == menuSelect ? "* " : "") + menuOptions[i] + (i == menuSelect ? "<--" : ""));
            }

            var keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();

            if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow && menuSelect != menuOptions.Length - 1)
            {
                menuSelect++;
            }
            else if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow && menuSelect >= 1)
            {
                menuSelect--;
            }
            else if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                switch (menuSelect)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Newcustomer();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        NewStaff();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Service();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Reparation();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Garantie();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Newcustomer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New Customer ...");
        Console.Write("Press Enter to Continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void NewStaff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New Staff ...");
        Console.Write("Press Enter to Continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Service()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service ...");
        Console.Write("Press Enter to Continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Reparation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reparation ...");
        Console.Write("Press Enter to Continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Garantie()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Garantie ...");
        Console.Write("Press Enter to Continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

It works fine for me:

[image]